# is there a bettter way to read in file characters than this snippet of code?

Tags: c++, while-loop, char, ifstream

I am trying to make this snippet of code better. What this code basically does is takes in a char filename which then reads the file. Note the file has a comment on top or a line of string that ends with `\n`, but this code from what I think skips and starts taking char from 512, but I am not sure.

```cpp
void RunList(char *filename)
{
    List <int> list;
    ListItr <int> listItr = list.zeroth();
    ifstream inf(filename);
    char command, s[512];
    int value;
    inf.getline(s,512);
    while (inf >> command >> value)
    {
        if (command == 'i')
            list.insert(value, listItr);
        else
            list.remove(value);
    }
}
```

Here's what I have until now, when I learned about the `.ignore` and what I could understand to make it better.

I don't fully understand the line `char command, s[512]` and how it plays a role in the while loop.

```cpp
void RunList(char *filename)
{
    List<int> myList;
    ListItr<int> myItr = myList.zeroth();
    ifstream inf(filename);
    file.ignore(256, '\n');
    char command , s[1];
    int value;
    inf.getline(s,1);

    while (inf >> command >> value)
    {
        if (command == 'i')
            list.insert(value, MyItr);
        else
            list.remove(value);
    }
```

Edit: here's a snippet of file being read in. The file has an 500000 input of char then followed by an int ex: i13. For example, the first line is a string and then after that it is followed by a ton of these.

Has a series of 500,000 insertions in order from 1 to 500000

```
i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 i10 i11 i12 i13 i14 i15 i16 i17 i18 i19 i20 i21 ...
```

Comment: Show us an example of the file contents.

Comment: Do you want to improve this code or just understand what it does? It might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you wrote it.

Comment: i would undersatnd the first one and build on the second one

Comment: What you have is fine but you don't need the `inf.getline(s, 1)`.

Comment: really ? how so if you could explain it a bit more or a link that would be super cool ! i thoughti needed it to read in from file.

Comment: thnaks for the help guys!!! it should be inf.ignore my smol